# XAMPP - How to login to PHPMyAdmin ? Password do not match

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I cannot log in to PHPMyAdmin when using XAMPP. Tried many different configurations with config.inc file but I cannot log in. My password "xxxx" is not valid, tried also without password and nothing.

Could you suggest what should I try to do to grant access to PHPMyAdmin ?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after changing config file?

Comment: root password to local environment mysql with xampp is typically empty, have your tried that